# TypeError : unhashable type: list?

Tags: python, xlwt

I'm trying to write excel file using XLWT from a CSV file(zipcode to State) but when i open csv and take statename from there then get this error otherwise if i set some hardcode value then it's executing.

```
import xlwt
import csv
row = 1
excelFile = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
sheet1 = excelFile.add_sheet('SampleData')
sheet1.col(0).width = 5000
sheet1.col(1).width = 5000
sheet1.write(0, 0, "Zip")
sheet1.write(0, 1, "State")
zip = '43215'
with open("usZipToCity.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            if zip in row:
                stateName = row[1]

sheet1.write(row, 0, zip)
sheet1.write(row, 1, stateName)
row += 1
excelFile.save("SampleData.xls")
```

**Error Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/scrapingtasks/toddkreal_property/Tester.py", line 47, in <module>
    sheet1.write(row, 0, zip)
  File "C:\Users\muhammadhamaadlatif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1088, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "C:\Users\muhammadhamaadlatif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1139, in row
    if indx not in self.__rows:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: You are passing in a list as a column or row reference.

Comment: You reused `row` for the CSV reading loop, so `row` is now  a list and not `1` anymore.

Comment: Now i see, i made a slang mistake. Thanks for correcting sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

As Martijn pointed out, you are using `row` for two different purposes:

- to hold a line of parsed csv ;
- to hold the index of the next row of the Excel file you will write.

The quickest way to fix this is to use a different variable name for each purposes. For example, you can rename `row` to `csvrow` in lines 13, 14, 15 and 16 of the code you provided.

If you have more time, I suggest you take a look at the following code. It includes a few stylistic fixes to your intial implementation as well as a `write_row()` function you might find interesting.

```
import xwlt
import csv

from itertools import count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create an Excel file
    EXCELFILE = xwlt.WorkBook(encoding="utf-8")
    # Setup a sheet
    SHEET = EXCELFILE.add_sheet('SampleData')
    SHEET.col(0).width = 5000
    SHEET.col(1).width = 5000

    # Define an easy way to write a row of data to SHEET
    ROW_IDX = count()
    def write_row(*args):
        """Writes a row of data into SHEET"""
        row_idx = next(ROW_IDX)
        for col_idx, arg in enumerate(args):
            SHEET.write(row_idx, col_idx, arg)

    # Write the header (first row)
    write_row("Zip", "State")

    # Set ZIP to the zip code we are interested in
    ZIP = '43215'

    # Parse the csv file
    with open("usZipToCity.csv", encoding="utf-8") as CSVFILE:
        for CSVROW in csv.reader(CSVFILE):
            if ZIP in CSVROW:
                # CSVROW[1] contains a state name
                write_row(ZIP, CSVROW[1])

    # Write the Excel file to disk
    EXCEFILE.save("SampleData.xls")
```

*Note*: it is not clear to me from your code whether you expect to find several matching rows in the csv file. If not, you should probably use `break` after the first match.